# How to load a plugin into Revolution R v6.1?

Tags: r, svn, plugins, revolution-r

I would like to install an SVN client, such as AnkhSVN, into Revolution R v6.1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Revolution R is build on Microsoft Visual Studio 2008, so it is possible to load some plugins designed for Visual Studio 2008. The normal option `Tools..Options..Environment..Add-in/Macros Security` is not supported, thus these instructions (which also appear for an earlier version of Revolution R in the user manual).

You can get AnkhSVN to work inside Revolution R Enterprise by doing the following:

1. Install the latest version of AnkhSVN.
2. Copy all files in the directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\AnkhSN 2` to the folder(s):

   ```
   C:\Revolution\R-Enterprise-6.0\IDE64\PackagesToLoad
   ```

   and

   ```
   C:\Revolution\R-Enterprise-6.0\IDE32\PackagesToLoad
   ```
3. Exit Revolution R Enterprise.
4. Open a DOS commands window as Administrator and run the following commands in the directory:

   ```
   'C:\Revolution\R-Enteprise-6.0\IDE64'
   ```

   Commands:

   ```
   start /wait RevoIDE.exe /remove
   start /wait RevoIDE.exe /setup
   ```

   (this last command will take about 30 seconds to complete)
5. Start Revolution R Enterprise. The plugin should now be activated.